# Node v0.10.32 is no longer supported by Ember CLI

Tags: node.js, ember.js, ember-cli

I have already updated node version 0.12.9 but i am still getting this
Any quick fix !!!

```
DEPRECATION: Node v0.10.32 is no longer supported by Ember CLI. Please update to a more recent version of Node
```

when i ran `node -v` it gives me 0.12.9.

Comment: Which version of Ember-cli are you using? I'm using node 0.12.2 on ember-cli 1.13.12 and don't see that warning. (Assuming that's a warning that appears when running ember s)

Comment: Are you using `nvm`?

Comment: @KellySelden i have compiled node from source at ubuntu 14.04